# What code do we mdoify in functions.php for a WordPress child theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

I was following along to this example in the [official tutorial](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

But then they had this line

> where parent-style is the same $handle used in the parent theme when it registers it's stylesheet.

What does that even mean?

I am creating a child theme for Bazaar Lite and the directory name is `bazaar-lite`

How should I modify my file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bit of a typo in the docs, actually. If you look at the simpler example just above that one on [the doc page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), they use "parent-style" literally. You could still use "parent-style" no problem there.

So to answer your question, you should be able to use that code that you showed as is, without any modifications.

Hope this helps!